# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space при создании большого массива объектов (более 10 миллионов) в Java

Tags: java, массивы

У меня получилось создать массив около 2.7 миллионов, дальше ошибка памяти:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Зачем вам столько, если не секрет?

Comment: в большинстве случаев можно использовать пагинацию, стримы и прочее. Зачем держать в памяти 10кк, тем более я так понимаю не простых объектов?

Comment: Если что-то не влазит `on heap` - пора использовать `off heap` :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

У Вас просто кончилась память, выделенная под кучу(heap).
Если необходимо хранить всю информацию в памяти, то используйте ключи для JVM

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
-Xss<size>        set java thread stack siz
```

например: `java -Xmx6g myprogram`